# OracleSolaris 11.2 -- character device in /dev/*

Tags: solaris, device-driver, opensolaris

Normally in Linux PCI drivers may expose a control interface to user-land
via a character device, e.g. `/dev/drv_ctl`, and a user application can
read/write I/O control commands with `ioctl()` on the open file descriptor.

In Linux we create this with `register_chrdev()` kernel API.

I would like to have the same or similar mechanism and behaviour on Solaris, but seems that on Solaris it works slightly different; DDI routine `ddi_create_minor_node()` requires a node type indicating audio, block, net etc. device, this looks quite vague to me, for example what type a crypto PCI device belongs to?

Also, it seems that `ddi_create_minor_node()`  creates a node under `/devices/*` and not under `/dev/*`

I would appreciate if someone could clarify my doubts and point out at the right directions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you create a symlink under /dev yourself, using a name which is useful to you. That would point to your actual /devices path which was created by calling `ddi_create_minor_node()`. You'll find the list of ddi node types in `<sys/sunddi.h>`; for a crypto device (what even is that?) you'd probably want DDI_PSEUDO.